# Visual Studio 2019 - CMake Linux - Where to get list of macros?

Tags: linux, visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2019

When working with the CMake Linux project in Visual Studio 2019, every json file (e.g. task.vs.json, launch.vs.json) magically uses macros like:

- `${workspaceRoot}`
- `${env.xxx}`
- `${debugInfo.xxx}`
- `${cmake.xxx}`

How can one know the full list of options when documentation is scarce, and IntelliSense does not help? For the case of MSBuild, usually there will be a window of all the possible variables, along with their resolved values.

As an aside, is there a way to define variables at a per-user leve, so files like `launch.vs.json` can take take it in?  For example, defining `targetAddr=192.168.1.2`, and then use ${targetAddr} in the json file.  One method is to define the variable in the json file itself, but I wish to commit the file as a "default" for team members, and let team members inject values through variables, without making the json file "dirty".